# Copy and pasting within same column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently having difficulty copying the contents of a column and pasting it at the end of the same column. For example, if the column contents are red, orange, blue, green, purple in cells C1:C5 respectively, I'd like rows C6:C10 to have the same contents red, orange, blue, green and purple respectively. I'm having trouble doing so with the following code with an error saying

> this object does not support this property or method

. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Dim New_Last As Long, myRng As Range
New_Last = Sheets("Project").UsedRange.Rows.Count

With Sheets("Project")
    Set myRng = Sheets("Project").Range("Z2:Z" & New_Last)
    Selection.Copy Range("z2:z" & New_Last)
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Offset(New_Last, 0).Paste
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you've an issue with coping setting a range, but not using it; you have a "selection" copy, which may be outside of the range of the selection, e.g., selected 50 rows, but have specified to paste into 40 rows.

You also have the issue that you have Z1:Z&new_last pasting to Z2:Z&new_last, which is the same issue.

```
With Sheets("Project")
    Set myRng = .Range("Z2:Z" & New_Last) 
    myRng.Copy .Range("Z" & New_Last + 1)
End With
```

Simplified that you are just coping and pasting to a defined range; you can have a simple cell location to paste to and it will fill to the final row.

Comment: Thanks so much looks like I had that extra bit that was unnecessary and throwing the error

Comment: I think this will paste over the last row on column Z, shouldn't you offset the New_Last to the next row when pasting? Like in my answer below...

Comment: @Xabier Great catch, I forgot the +1 after New_Last.

Comment: Oh correct, yes I noticed after you shared your Cyril, and just added that myself. Thanks @Xabier

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want:

```
Dim New_Last As Long, myRng As Range
New_Last = Sheets("Project").UsedRange.Rows.Count

With Sheets("Project")
    Set myRng = .Range("Z2:Z" & New_Last)
    myRng.Copy Range("Z" & New_Last + 1)
End With
```